# How do I return a sorted list of the sum of numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list

```
numbers = [869, 1069, 1108, 1343, 389]
```

and i want to sort them in ascending order of the sum of the digits(ex:8+6+9 for 869)

## My input:

```
def s_num(nums):
    result = [sum(int(digit) for digit in str(number)) for number in numbers]
    return result
   
s_num = sorted(numbers,key=s_num)
print(s_num)
```

However, for some reason my output is the same as my initial list

```
print(s_num)
[869, 1069, 1108, 1343, 389]
```

How do i change my script to get the correct sorted list?

Comment: unrelated, but you are overwriting your function. You may want to use a different name for the variable.

Comment: Your key function is wrong. The argument is not the array of integers but an element taken from the array. What you want to do is process a single integer as input and return that integer's sum of the digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function should take an argument and return a value to use for sorting purposes. You should not iterate over the `numbers` array in that function. So do this:

```
numbers = [869, 1069, 1108, 1343, 389]
def s_num(num):
    return sum(map(int, str(num)))

result = sorted(numbers,key=s_num)
print(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1108, 1343, 1069, 389, 869]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Also how would I go about it if I have to write a program that displays the values in the list numbers in ascending order sorted by their largest prime factor

Comment: @codeybanks If my post answers your question, please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can map the digit characters of a string-converted number to integers so that you can pass them to the `sum` function:

```
def s_num(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))
```

With this change, `sorted(numbers, key=s_num)` would return:

```
[1108, 1343, 1069, 389, 869]
```

Comment: <function s_num at 0x00000263FBB20840> when i do the above and print sum and i get this output unfortunately

Comment: I don't think you're running my code correctly. Please run the demo: https://repl.it/repls/SpanishPrevailingPublishers

Comment: Thanks it works. Also how would I go about it if I have to write a program that displays the values in the list numbers in ascending order sorted by their largest prime factor

Comment: Glad to be of help. Finding the largest prime factor is really out of the scope of this question. Please post a new question if you have issues coding it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed out on using the `s_num(nums)` function argument correctly. Moreover, the sorted function already loops over the individual elements of the `numbers` list, so you don't need a nested loop in the `s_num(nums)` function.

````
def s_num(nums):
    digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(nums) ]
    return sum(digits)

s_num = sorted(numbers,key=s_num)
print(s_num)```
````

Comment: Thanks it works. Also how would I go about it if I have to write a program that displays the values in the list numbers in ascending order sorted by their largest prime factor

Answer (score 1):

You can do in a single line with `key` argument

```
sorted(numbers,key=lambda x:(sum(map(int,str(x)))))
```

Output

```
[1108, 1343, 1069, 389, 869]
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Also how would I go about it if I have to write a program that displays the values in the list numbers in ascending order sorted by their largest prime factor

Answer (score 1):

Your s_sum(nums) function is ignoring the parameter it receives (nums) and computing the sum of digits for all items of the numbers variable.  This will always be the same result and so you list isn't sorted.

You could change this to : `result = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(nums))` or use one of the suggested answers posted here.